# array_chunk into randomized chunks

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array, but I want each chunk that it's split between to be a different sized chunk each time, but somewhere between 6 and 8.

```
    function random_chunk($array){
     return array_chunk($array, rand(4,8));
    }
```

But that will only randomize the chunk one time. I want each array chunk to be a different size between 4 and 8 variables. The array I'm going to be using is one dimensional.

Comment: Can you post your array that you want to split in chunk?

Comment: `array_slice()` Maybe does the trick for you

Comment: Write a loop and do your own chunk algorithm.  I don't see the usefulness of this type of function.

Comment: `function random_chunk($array){
     $retVal = []; while (!empty($array)) { $retVal[] = array_splice($array, 0, rand(4,8)); } return $retVal;
    }`

Comment: So do you have a set number of elements in your input array?  What happens if the number of elements available is not possibly divided into chunks of 4 to 8?  Do you actually want subarrays of 4 to 8 elements or do you want 6 to 8 elements?  Your very short question seems to contradict itself.  I need to vote to close this one as Unclear.  If you come back to SO, please edit your question to clarify.